# Build a Map from a JSON using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've a RESTFUL WEB Service returning data in JSON format. Need to **build a Map from the JSON returned by the service using AngularJS**.

For instance, let the json be like as follows:

```
myJSON = [{
    id: 8,
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    id: 37,
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    id: 45,
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
}]
```

Need to build a map using id & value from the above JSON. I could imagine something like as follows:

```
var map = [myJSON.id : myJSON.value]
```

which would return something like

```
map = {8: "red", 37: "green", 45: "blue"}
```

A trivial solution would be looping thro' the JSON array and construct a map but is there any other method of achieving my GOAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `reduce` function on array. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Note that this has nothing to do with angular. This is vanilla js.

```
var mapped = myJSON.reduce(function(map, field) {
    map[field.id] = field.color;
    return map;
}, {});
```